# How to check if the input is in the value of the dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, input

I am going to ask the users for input.
This is my preferred scenario.
If the user enters Black as the input,
my code will check if the input is equal to one of the dictionary's values,
If it is equal, then print out the price value. I am new in python. Can anyone give me a help and try to make it simple? Thank you!

```
dict1 = {"item_id":101,"color":["Black","White"],"price":99}
input_color = input("Please fill in your color")
if input_color in dict1.values():
    print("Price = ",dict1[price])
else: print("your color is not supported")
```

[Here is the screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiIHR.png)

Comment: `if input_color in dict1['color']:`

Comment: Be aware that you will have to match the capitalisation exactly. If you don't want this, then put lower-case colours in the dictionary (e.g. `"black"`), and do `if input_color.lower() in dict1['color']:`

Comment: What @alaniwi said, also `dict1["price"]` - you're missing the quotes

Comment: thankyou @alaniwi @Grismar! That's what I want to perform

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is access the values of a specific key in your dictionary (dict1). To do that in python you use the .get(key_name) method, which returns the value/s of the requested key.

```
dict1 = {"item_id":101,"color":["Black","White"],"price":99}
input_color = input("Please fill in your color")
if input_color in dict1.get("color"):
    print("Price = ",dict1.get("price"))
else: print("your color is not supported")
```